# Assign a unique id to every request in a spring-based web application

Tags: java, spring

I created a spring-based Java web application,

for each request, an instance of 'controller class' will be created to handle the request.

in the business logic, I want to do some logging with a UNIQUE ID automatically assigned to each request so that I can track what the program exactly did.

the log may be like this(2 requests at same time):

```
[INFO] request #XXX: begin.
[INFO] request #XXX: did step 1
[INFO] request #YYY: begin.
[INFO] request #XXX: did step 2
[INFO] request #YYY: did step 1
[INFO] request #XXX: end.
[INFO] request #YYY: end.
```

from the log, I can realize:
req #XXX: begin-step1-step2-end
req #YYY: begin-step1-end

I hope the logging can be called easily everywhere in the code,
so I don't want to add a parameter of "requestId" to every java function,

It's perfect if the logging tool can be called in a static way:

```
LOG.doLog("did step 1");
```

any idea of how can I do this? thank you :)

Comment: How do you create the controler instance?

Comment: can you post controller class?

Comment: the controller is a prototype-scope spring bean

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have three different problems to solve:

1. Generate an unique id for each request
2. Store the id and access it everywhere in the code
3. Log the id automatically

I would suggest this approaches

1. Use a Servlet filter or a [ServletRequestListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html) (as suggested by M. Deinum) or a [Spring Handler Interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)  to intercept the request in a general way, there you can create a unique id, maybe with an [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)
2. You can save the id as an attribute of the request, in this case the id would propagate just in the controller layer, not in the services. So you can solve the problem using a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable or asking Spring to do the magic with the [RequestContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html): the RequestContextHolder will allow you to access the request of that specific thread, and the request attributes as well, in the service layer. The RequestContextHolder use ThreadLocal variable to store the request. You can access the request in this way:

   ```
   ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
   // Extract the request
   HttpServletRequest request = attr.getRequest();
   ```
3. There is an interesting [article](http://www.jajakarta.org/log4j/jakarta-log4j-1.1.3/docs/deepExtension.html) ([2018 alternative](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html)), if you are using log4j, on the customization of the pattern layout of the logger. However, youncan simply create a proxy of your logging system interface and append manually the id to every logged string.

Comment: Instead of a `Filter` I would probably create a `ServletRequestListener` as that is executed before all filters. Especially in a Servlet 3.0 environment (where you don't always know what filters you get), this can be handy. Next to that I would keep it away from frameworks so I would store it in a `ThreadLocal` (maybe a `RequestIdHolder` wrapping it like springs `LocaleContextHolder`).

Comment: i just tested ThreadLocal way, it seems logged the same GUID for different requests. thread re-used? is there a thread pool?

Comment: How do you set the Guid? Are you using the filter/listener?

Comment: There are some "remote service call" in my project. In fact, I want to  print the sequence of the service call during execution. I implemented an interceptor before "the call" and print ID+CallInfo. With the help of a request-scope unique ID, I can extract the sequence I want from the mixed logs.

Comment: I just tried to add a ThreadLocal<String> into the interceptor, and assigned It an random UUID as initial value. But It always return the same ID while I sending requests one by one.

Comment: Different IDs returned if I send two requests at the same time.

Comment: In the interceptor/filter/listener you should generate every time a new Guid. This Guid should saved in the request or binded to a ThreadLocal. When you have to call the remote procedure, you have just to read that variable (using the RequestContextHolder or accessing the ThreadLocal variable). I updated the answer with some code.

Answer (score 40):

You can also try using [MDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) class of Log4j. The MDC is managed on a per thread basis.
If you are using a ServletRequestListner then you can set the unique Id in the requestInitialized.

```
import org.apache.log4j.MDC;
import java.util.UUID;

public class TestRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {    
protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestRequestListener.class);

 public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent arg0) {
    LOGGER.debug("++++++++++++ REQUEST INITIALIZED +++++++++++++++++");

    MDC.put("RequestId", UUID.randomUUID());

 }

 public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent arg0) {
    LOGGER.debug("-------------REQUEST DESTROYED ------------");
    MDC.clear(); 
 }
}
```

Now anywhere in the code if you do a log either debug, warn or error. Whatever you had put in the MDC will be printed out. You need to configure you log4j.properties. Notice the %X{RequestId}. This referes to the key name which is inserted in the requestInitialized() above.

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS} %p %C %X{RequestId} - %m%n
```

I also found this link to be helpful -> [What is the difference between Log4j's NDC and MDC facilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134734/what-is-the-difference-between-log4js-ndc-and-mdc-facilities)

Comment: For the spring boot users out there, you can configure the logging pattern in your application.yml. `logging.pattern.console: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS} %p %C %X{RequestId} - %m%n`

Comment: Ugh beware! Understand that when using Spring WebTemplate for example and other cases wherein there is another thread pool for the client interaction... when a thread from that pool is assigned a task it *does not* automagically get a copy of the MDC/thread-local info. The Spring WebTemplate HTTP thread pool is not a child-thread of the caller so the MDC does *not* get copied. It will have some arbitrary value from a previous invocation. Need to intercept and copy into the thread from the pool any thread-local data.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the "Fish Tagging" in Log4j 2. It is the same idea like MDC and NDC (thread-basis) as described in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html

Here you can use either the Thread Context Stack or the Thread Context Map. An example for the Map looks like this:

```
//put a unique id to the map
ThreadContext.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString()

//clear map
ThreadContext.clearMap();
```

And for the pattern in log4j2.xml you can also use the %X{KEY} tag.

To put a new id to the map (for example for every incoming request) you can do that in an ServletRequestListener implementation how Sharadr described it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using spring 4.1.3 or later, you can wrap your request into a custom subclass of [ContentCachingRequestWrapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html) class.

```
public class MyHTTPServletRequestWrapper extends ContentCachingRequestWrapper {

    private UUID uuid;

    public MyHTTPServletRequestWrapper (HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public UUID getUUID() {
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

In your spring controller, add the request to the method's param, and cast it to your custom wrapper:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String find(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id, HttpServletRequest request) {
        MyHTTPServletRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = (WGHTTPServletRequestWrapper)request;
        System.out.println(wrappedRequest.getUUID());
...
}
```

You will need to user filter though, to connect the dots:

```
public class RequestLoggingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest requestToCache = new MyHTTPServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
System.out.println(((WGHTTPServletRequestWrapper)requestToCache).getUUID());
        chain.doFilter(requestToCache, response);

    }
}
```

You will find that the printlin from RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter() and from controllers getId() will produce the same UUID.

You will just need to play around to use the UUID in appropriate places, but at least you have the value in your controller where is the start of your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@Scope` annotation to load a new instance of the service for each request.

See official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html)

If you want to inject this in a non-request aware service, you should use proxyMode option. more info [here](http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/spring-scoped-proxy-beans-an-alternative-to-method-injection/) (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731092/spring-request-scope-bean) stack question)

Answer (score 0):

You must use a database sequence (if your database is ORACLE) as follows

```
create sequence "sequence_Name";

String uniqueString=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). createSQLQuery("SELECT \"sequence_Name\".nextval FROM dual").list().get(0);
```

Comment: --@amirazizkhani 
It seems to me you don't understand. You are a genius :))
Just like UUID.randomUUID(), you can use a database sequence (in Oracle if you can work with it) to generate a Unique Id incrementally and then assign it to any request.