# How to use Session Scoped Component in Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-ioc

Count.java:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Count {
    Integer i;
    public Count() {
        this.i = 0;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @Autowired private Count count;
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        if(count.i == null) i == 0;
        else i++;
        model.addAttribute("count",String.valueOf(count.i));
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

But every i run this controller (/greeting), it always increase the i even when I close the browser, so how can i use this Session Scoped Component in Singleton Controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring request scope bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731092/spring-request-scope-bean)

Comment: Create a getter for `i`.

Comment: @zeroflagL: It works, thanks. But can you explain it. At first, the session bean act like a global variable, it increase even when i deleted cookies. But use a setter/getter instead i++; it works like a charm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The proxy only intercepts method calls. In your case the following happens:

```
@Autowired private Count count;
```

Creates a proxy that looks like an instance of count and therefore also has an `i` field. But since the proxy is not the real thing, the `Count` constructor is not called and `i`remains uninitialized. That's why you always get `null`.

Now let's introduce a getter:

```
class Count {
  ...
  public Integer getI() {
    return i;
  }
```

When you invoke `getI()` the proxy first checks if there is an instance of the `Count` bean for the current session. If there is none, one is created. This also means that the `Count` constructor is called and `i` is now initalized. Then the proxy delegates the call to the bean's `getI()` that will return the value of `i`.

Comment: Your anwser also explained what is proxy and how it works :D