# Cassandra: customer data per keyspace

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

**Problem**: one of our new customers want the data to be stored in his own country (law regulations). However we use existing customer's data spread across few datacenters in different countries.

**Question**: how we can separate new customer's data to reside in its own country without much changing existing Cassandra architecture?

**Potential Solution #1**: to use separate keyspace for this customer. Schemas will be the same between keyspaces what adds the complexity for data migration and so on. DataStax support confirmed that it is possible to configure keyspace per region. 
However Spring Data Cassandra we use, doesn't allow to choose keyspace dynamically.
The only way is to use CqlTemplate and to run `use keyspace blabla` everytime before the call or to add keyspace before the table `select * from blabla.mytable` but it sounds as a hack for me.

**Potential Solution #2** to use separate environment for new client but management rejects to do it.

Any other ways to achieve this goal?

Comment: I don't see how you can achieve it without creating a new keyspace if all customers share the same keyspace and its data is spread in data centers in multiple countries.
The keyspace is where you would specify to only put the data in specific data centers (the ones in the customer country).

Comment: @Edu, yes, we are thinking in the same way (potential solution #1) but with Spring Data Cassandra it is not possible to use dynamic switch of keyspace (at least my few hours research didn't help).

Comment: @walv: why do you say tat adding "keyspace before the table select * from blabla.mytable" sounds like a hack? It's a normal way to reference a table and is pretty used. It's just like a fully qualified name of the table.

Comment: @walv I don't know the specifics of your use case, but it seems like you will always need to know the customer region by request and define the keyspace on a "by request lifestyle", using it in the cassandra queries that are made by the customer in that request.

Comment: @Edu, yes, each http request will contain companyId of the user, so we can easily map what company belongs to what cluster.

Comment: @Horia, the problem is that it will work only for direct CQL queries, but I would really love to leverage all the features of Spring Data which, unfortunatelly, not designed for dynamic keyspace resolution.

Comment: @walv, choosing keyspace dynamically means, that you have to do it in runtime. Did I understood it correctly? So setting keyspace during deployment or during booting the application is not an option.

Comment: @Oresztesz correct

Comment: @walv - I have an idea, but it needs some preparation.Will be back soon to this thread with answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update 3

Example and explanation below is same as in GitHub

## Update 2

The example in GitHub is now working. The most future proof solution seemed to be using repository extensions. Will update the example below soon.

## Update

Notice that the solution I originally posted had some flaws that I discovered during JMeter tests. The Datastax Java driver reference advises to avoid setting keyspace through `Session` object. You have to set keyspace explicitly in every query.

I've updated the GitHub repository and also changed solution's description.

> Be very careful though: if the session is shared by multiple threads,
>   switching the keyspace at runtime could easily cause unexpected query failures.
>
> Generally, the recommended approach is to use a single session with no
>   keyspace, and prefix all your queries.

## Solution Description

I would set-up a separate keyspace for this specific customer and provide support for changing keyspace in the application. We used this approach previously with RDBMS and JPA in production. So, I would say it can work with Cassandra as well. Solution was similar as below.

I will describe briefly how to prepare and set-up Spring Data Cassandra to configure target keyspace on each request.

## Step 1: Preparing your services

I would define first how to set the tenant ID on each request. A good example would be in-case-of REST API is to use a specific HTTP header that defines it:

```
Tenant-Id: ACME
```

Similarly on every remote protocol you can forward tenant ID on every message. Let's say if you're using AMQP or JMS, you can forward this inside message header or properties.

## Step 2: Getting tenant ID in application

Next, you should store the incoming header on each request inside your controllers. You can use `ThreadLocal` or you can try using a request-scoped bean.

```
@Component
@Scope(scopeName = "request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class TenantId {

    private String tenantId;

    public void set(String id) {
        this.tenantId = id;
    }

    public String get() {
        return tenantId;
    }
}
```

---

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    @Autowired
    private TenantId tenantId;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userByName")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUserByUsername(
            @RequestHeader("Tenant-ID") String tenantId,
            @RequestParam String username) {
        // Setting the tenant ID
        this.tenantId.set(tenantId);
        // Finding user
        User user = userRepo.findOne(username);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user.getUsername(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

## Step 3: Setting tenant ID in data-access layer

Finally you should extend `Repository` implementations and set-up keyspace according to the tenant ID

```
public class KeyspaceAwareCassandraRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleCassandraRepository<T, ID>  {

    private final CassandraEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata;
    private final CassandraOperations operations;

    @Autowired
    private TenantId tenantId;

    public KeyspaceAwareCassandraRepository(
            CassandraEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata,
            CassandraOperations operations) {
        super(metadata, operations);
        this.metadata = metadata;
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    private void injectDependencies() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport
                .processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
                getServletContext());
    }

    private ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest().getServletContext();
    }

    @Override
    public T findOne(ID id) {
        injectDependencies();
        CqlIdentifier primaryKey = operations.getConverter()
                .getMappingContext()
                .getPersistentEntity(metadata.getJavaType())
                .getIdProperty().getColumnName();

        Select select = QueryBuilder.select().all()
                .from(tenantId.get(),
                        metadata.getTableName().toCql())
                .where(QueryBuilder.eq(primaryKey.toString(), id))
                .limit(1);

        return operations.selectOne(select, metadata.getJavaType());
    }

    // All other overrides should be similar
}
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCassandraRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = KeyspaceAwareCassandraRepository.class)
public class DemoApplication {
...
}
```

Let me know if there are any issues with the code above.

## Sample code in GitHub

https://github.com/gitaroktato/spring-boot-cassandra-multitenant-example

## References

- [Example: Using JPA interceptors](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/interceptors/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/interceptors/ApplicationConfiguration.java)
- [Spring @RequestHeader example](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-requestheader-example/)
- [Spring request-scoped beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731092/spring-request-scope-bean)
- [Datastax Java Driver Reference](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/)

Comment: for step 1 and 2, we handle it on nginx level, because each API contains company ID, e.g. api/v1/companies/123/...
Step #3 will probably work for JPA but definitely not for Spring Data Cassandra. And that's what I am looking for - how to set keyspace in Spring Data Cassandra in runtime.

Comment: For step 1&2 you can forward customer context from nginx to the applications by rewriting the HTTP requests. Application has to know which customer request needs to be handled on a per-request basis. What's the issue with step #3 exactly? Spring data JPA can interoperate with Cassandra as well. Do you want to just avoid JPA in your codebase and use spring-data-cassandra with another interface?

Comment: for steps 1 & 2, you are right, by company ID from url, we define what keyspace should be used. Regarding step #3, I am not sure that JPA can operate with Cassandra. Maybe you mean that Spring Data can operate with Cassandra but not JPA? With the idea of method interception, it sounds good. The only thing I have doubt is that if I substitute EntityManager with CassandraTemplate (singleton), and I query "USE KEYSPACE" then I can get unpredictable read/writes in multithreaded environment, because Cassandra has no transactions. But maybe I understand something wrong?

Comment: I have to dig deeper to understand how interfacing between Spring data and Cassandra driver interoperates. I've seen EntityManager interface usage in official reference, but injecting CassandraTemplate should simplify things. At the end you will execute `USE KEYSPACE` per request. I think it's a manageable overhead. We had to execute a performance test with multiple client types and put a decent load on the cluster to ensure that implementation was production ready.

Comment: You can verify if you got unpredictable read/writes with performance testing. For us this approach didn't have meaningful overhead.

Comment: yes, true, I need to try instead of guess. Marking this as correct solution as there is no more alternatives and this solution makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, I will correct this from time-to-time whenever I have some more time for it.

Comment: I corrected some programming errors based on our discussion, now it works for me locally.

Answer (score 0):

Advice with 2 keyspaces is correct.
If question is about having just 2 keyspaces why not configure 2 keyspaces.
for Region Dependent client - write to both
for others - write to one (main) keyspace only.
No data migration will be required.
Here is sample how to configure Spring Repositories to hit different keyspaces:
http://valchkou.com/spring-boot-cassandra.html#multikeyspace

the choice of repository can be simple if else

```
if (org in (1,2,3)) { 
   repoA.save(entity)
   repoB.save(entity)
} else {
   repoA.save(entity)
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that in our case, it is hard to predict that we will need only two keyspaces and not more. Tomorrow can be third and day after - forth. That's why we were looking for the dynamic solution to avoid that PITA in the future.

Comment: If you have multiple session for each keyspace, application has to keep a separate connection pool for each tenant. That can cause unnecessary overhead in-case of number of tenants are increasing.

Answer (score 0):

After many back and forth, we have decided to not do the dynamic keyspace resolution within the same JVM.

It was taken the decision to have dedicated Jetty/Tomcat per keyspace and on nginx router level to define to what server the request should be redirected to (based on companyId from the request url).

For example, all our endpoints have `/companyId/<value>` so based on the value, we can redirect the request to proper server which uses correct keyspace.

Comment: I really think you can do it in the same instance, but without extending the `spring-data-cassandra` library it's not possible. Too bad that they're not introducing multi-tenancy as an option. There's one closed JIRA ticket, but nothing more related to this feature: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-330?jql=labels%20%3D%20cassandra%20AND%20labels%20%3D%20multi-tenancy

Comment: Somehow I'll try to push this and finish extending the library to have multi-tenant option. Just to have an example on how to do it.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative solution. You can have a look