# Spring bean management using @Autowired

Tags: spring, spring-4

I have a messaging call that will process my payload which starts from `MyClass`. In load test i see that the first payload is getting over written by the next. All my classes are spring managed by `@Autowired`. Obviously the bean scope is singleton and thats why this is happening. But i do not want to use `new` operator and want it to be spring annotation configured. Is there any way to fix this issue of losing data ?

**UPDATE**

My configuration looks like below :

```
Public class MyClass {
...
@Autowired
public MyService myService;
...
}

@Component
@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyService{

@Autowired
public Aone one;

@Autowired
public Atwo two;
...
}

@Component
@Scope(value="prototype")
public class Aone {

}
```

I am attempting this configuration after suggestions from net. For every call i get in `MyClass` a new instance of `MyService` will be created and from there on all other instances like `Aone` / `Atwo` should have new instance, will this configuration be ok ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731092/spring-request-scope-bean

Comment: I cant use request scope as its not a web application